# How to Call function with onPress(on click) that is defined in useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have Logout screen in which i defined Logout button, by pressing logout button I am removing token and want to redirect to login screen, when i do press it's removing token but not redirecting to login, it's redirect when I am closing or reopening or after refreshing.
to overcome this problem i am using `useEffect hook` for compnentDidUpdate or something like that like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
 const handleLogout = () => {
  // dispatch(logoutAction());
};
handleLogout();
}, [handleLogout]);
```

But when I am calling handleLogout on onPress, Error occur variable handleLogout not defined, because of scopes you cannot use variable outside its scope.

```
 <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={handleLogout}>
    <View style={styles.logoutBtn}>
      <Text style={{color: '#FFFFFF'}}>Logout</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableNativeFeedback>
```

Answer (score 1):

just define this function outside of use effect, and only reference it and call it inside useEffect.

```
...
const handleLogout = () => {
  // dispatch(logoutAction());
};

useEffect(() => {
    handleLogout();
}, [handleLogout]);

return (
    <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={handleLogout}>
    <View style={styles.logoutBtn}>
      <Text style={{color: '#FFFFFF'}}>Logout</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableNativeFeedback>
)
...
```

But im not sure if this is 'good' practice, since this might cause useEffect triggers on renders, since you are passing a function as dependency. So it just looks weird from the get go in my opinion. What i would do , ditch the useEffect all together, and maybe try adding some extra function in dispatch. Something like

```
...
const navigation = useNavigation()

const handleLogout = () => {
  dispatch(logoutAction());
  navigation.navigate('YourInitialScreen')
};

return (
    <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={handleLogout}>
    <View style={styles.logoutBtn}>
      <Text style={{color: '#FFFFFF'}}>Logout</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableNativeFeedback>
)
...
```

Its somwhat hard to understand what exactly you are trying to do without not knowing what this `dispatch` really does. But maybe this helps in your brainstorming.

Answer (score 0):

Move function definition outside `useEffect`:

```
const handleLogout = () => {
  // dispatch(logoutAction());
};

useEffect(() => {
  handleLogout();
}, [handleLogout]);
```

Comment: it's doing what i want. i am running that function on onclick so there is no reason to call handlelogout inside useffect, i tried it's still work like that work without using effec